# Expectation values in the perturbative renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization

My question is related to the perturbative renormalization group:

Suppose we are given an action of the form 
$$
S=S_{0}+\delta{S}
$$
where $S_{0}$ is some "unperturbed action" and $\delta{S}$ is a "small" perturbation of the form 
$$
\delta{S}=\int\mathrm{d}^{D}r \sum_{n} g_{n} \alpha^{\Delta_{n}-D}\phi_{n}(r)
$$
where the $g_{n}$ are dimensionless coupling constants, $\alpha$ is some ultra-violet cutoff, $\Delta_{n}$ the scaling dimension of the operator $\phi_{n}$ and
$D$ is the spatial dimensionality. 
The deviation of the partition from its unperturbed value is up to second
order in perturbation theory given by 
$$
\frac{Z}{Z_{0}}=1+\sum_{n}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{D}r}{\alpha^{D-\Delta_{n}}}g_{n}
\langle\phi_{n}(r)\rangle_{0}
+
\sum_{n,m}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{D}r_{1}}{\alpha^{D-\Delta_{n}}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{D}r_{2}}{\alpha^{D-\Delta_{m}}}g_{n}g_{m}
\langle\phi_{n}(r_{1})\phi_{m}(r_{2})\rangle_{0}+...
$$
where $\langle...\rangle_{0}$ denotes the average with respect to the unperturbed action.

Question: 
How can I figure out if a certain expectation value of operators in this expansion vanishes?

For example: Suppose I am given two system (say a metal and a superconductor) 
and I am introducing a tunnel coupling $\Psi^{\dagger}_{1}(x_{1})\Psi_{2}(x_{2})+\text{h.c.}$ where $\Psi^{\dagger}_{1}$ ($\Psi^{\dagger}_{2}$)
is the electron creation operator in system 1 (2). 
Is it true that $\langle\Psi^{\dagger}_{1}(x_{1})\Psi_{2}(x_{2})+\text{h.c.}\rangle_{0}=0$? Intuitively I would say yes because in the "uncoupled" theory $S_{0}$ the two system don't know from each other. 
On the other hand, it is not clear how the coupling then actually shows 
up in the partition function $Z$ of the coupled system if these expectation values are vanishing.

I would be happy if someone could provide a clarification for me.